# How to get href url if href contains in multiple div tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery can i  get href url if href attribute contains in anchor tag in div tag

```
<div id="testing">
    <a onclick="window.location='http://linkedin.com'>linked</a>
    <div id="my_div">
        <a onclick="window.location='http://google.com'>google</a>
        <a href="http://facebook.com">facebook</a>
        <a onclick="window.location='http://gmail.com'>gmail</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `onclick` instead of `href`?

Comment: Please add the attempts you've made to solve this issue yourself. StackOverflow != freelancer.com. Also it's very unclear what you're trying to do here. What values are you trying to retrieve from that block of HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
alert($('#my_div>a:nth-child(2)')[0].href);
```